# how to use owl-carousel in react.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, web, owl-carousel

I am working on a project using **react** (javascript framework). I want to use **owl-carousel**, but it is not working. It keeps throwing this error.

```js
OwlCarousel.js:1758 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fn')
    at OwlCarousel.js:1758:1
    at OwlCarousel.js:1795:1
    at OwlCarousel.js:2:1
    at ./node_modules/react-owl-carousel/umd/OwlCarousel.js (OwlCarousel.js:5:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/components/Homepage/Homepage.jsx (Divider.jsx:22:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
```

**steps to recreate**

`react version 18.2.0` 
`react-owl-carousel version 2.3.3` 
`bootstrap version 5.3.0`

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject a global window. **jQuery first.**

you can use html script tag to inject jquery as well.

go to the index.html of your react project.

`public/index.html`

```html
<body>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> 
</body>
```